# Flutter with ios 17

Tags: android, ios, flutter, xcode

Since I updated to iOS 17 I get that I must perform this same configuration that I have already verified and when I run the app on the physical device it opens xcode.

```
 You may be prompted to give access to control Xcode. Flutter uses Xcode to run your app. If access is not allowed, you can change this through your Settings > Privacy & Security > Automation.
```

```
enter image description here
```

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same behavior. After browsing the web I found out that this is expected behavior

[here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/134667) you can double-check it

[here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/133465) because of what we have such behavior now

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same issue on my Intel MacBook Pro 2017 model.

`You may be prompted to give access to control Xcode. Flutter uses Xcode to run your app. If access is not allowed, you can change this through your Settings > Privacy & Security > Automation.`

`The Dart VM Service was not discovered after 60 seconds. This is taking much longer than expected... Open the Xcode window the project is opened in to ensure the app is running. If the app is not running, try selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem.`

> But the application is running after sometimes.